# Where are files located in Sagemaker Studio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I have seen answers to this question and the answer is always that these files are located in

`/home/ec2-user/Sagemaker/`

however when I'm in Terminal in Sagemaker Studio I don't see this. It seems that Sagemaker Studio has a different directory than whichever Sagemaker service other askers are using. This is what my command line looks like when I do `pwd` in the directory:

```
sagemaker-user@studio$ pwd
/home/sagemaker-user/sagepipeline_nonomethod/source_dir
sagemaker-user@studio$
```

When I do

`os.chdir('/home/sagemaker-user/sagepipeline_nonomethod/source_dir')`

inside my jupyter notebook however I get an error that says there is no such directory. So there must be some prefix to the directory that I am missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you should be able to access the directory at `/root/sagepipeline_nonomethod/source_dir` within your notebook. Explaination follows:

---

If you open a *terminal* in the Launcher under *Utilities and files*, you will arrive at a **system terminal**. It's the compute environment living in SageMaker Studio, instead of the container where your notebook (kernel) lives.

The `/home/sagemaker-user` directory is a mountpoint of an EFS, where your Jupyter file browser points to.

```
sagemaker-user@studio$ df -h
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay             32G  5.3M   32G   1% /
tmpfs               64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm                395M     0  395M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1     160G   26G  135G  16% /opt/.sagemakerinternal
127.0.0.1:/200005  8.0E   40M  8.0E   1% /home/sagemaker-user
devtmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/tty
tmpfs              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/firmware
```

To access the terminal of the container environment, go to *Launcher* > *Notebooks and compute resources* > *Open image terminal*

The same EFS is mounted on `/root`

```
root@datascience-1-0-ml-t3-medium-1abf3407f667f989be9d86559395:~# df -h
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay             32G   40K   32G   1% /
tmpfs               64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm                395M     0  395M   0% /dev/shm
127.0.0.1:/200005  8.0E   40M  8.0E   1% /root
/dev/nvme0n1p1     160G   24G  137G  15% /opt/.sagemakerinternal
devtmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/tty
tmpfs              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/firmware
```

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because your files and notebooks in SageMaker Studio exist *separately* to the machine running the kernel to execute your code.

SageMaker Studio is, in essence, just a theme for Jupyter with a few added features. In the below diagram, you can see that your Studio interface and files are hosted by the "*JupyterServer App*", while the instances that execute your code are separate machines running containers.

The [Amazon SageMaker Studio Notebooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks.html) documentation provides a helpful overview of this architecture. See the diagram below.

[image]

Your question appears to be specific to an issue you're having, however. If you create a cell in your notebook and execute `!pwd` and `!ls`, you should find that the files available match those in the SageMaker Studio sidebar.